# Why migrating laravel app with into postgres I got error with boolean field?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm trying to migrate a Laravel app with `spatie/laravel-translatable` 6.3 from MySQL 8 into Postgres 14: in a table defined

```php
Schema::create('quiz_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->json('name')->comment('This column is used for i18n support');
        $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
```

and in `app/Models/QuizCategory.php`:

```
class QuizCategory extends Model
{
    use HasTranslations;

    protected $table = 'quiz_categories';
    public $translatable = ['name'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'boolean',
        'name' => 'json'
    ];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'active'];

    public function scopeGetByActive($query, $active = null)
    {
        if (! isset($active)) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where($this->table . '.active', (bool)$active);
    }
```

But with request

```
$quizCategories = QuizCategory::orderBy('name', 'desc')
    ->getByActive($filterActive)->get();
```

I got error:

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type json LINE 1: ...s" where "quiz_categories"."active" = $1 order by "name" des... ^ HINT: Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.
>
> SELECT * FROM "quiz_categories" WHERE "quiz_categories"."active" = 1 ORDER BY "name" DESC

Testing the SQL query in PhpgMyAdmin looks like I need :

a) to remake request to be rendered as

```
 "quiz_categories"."active" = true
```

Not sure how can I do it in eloquent?

b) I need to remove

```
ORDER BY "name" DESC
```

Can I make ordering by JSON field somehow?

MySQL executed my code, but I am not sure that it worked correctly

**UPDATED_INFO :**
I returned to this issue and looks like I skipped something last time, as with code:

```
$quizCategories = QuizCategory::query()
    ->getByActive()
    ->orderByRaw('name->"$.en"', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I got error :

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "$.en" does not exist LINE 1: select * from "quiz_categories" order by name->"$.en" ^
SELECT * FROM "quiz_categories" ORDER BY name->"$.en"
```

What is wrong ? Please give a reference to docs where such code is used...

**UPDATED_INFO # 2 :**
With request :

```
$quizCategories = QuizCategory::query()
    ->getByActive()
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("json_extract('name', '$.en')"), 'desc')
  ->get();
```

I got error :

```
 function json_extract(unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

Searching in next I found method json_extract_path, but with code :

```
 $quizCategories = QuizCategory::query()
    ->getByActive()
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("json_extract_path('name', '$.en')"), 'desc')
  ->get();
```

I got different error :

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json LINE 1: ...from "quiz_categories" order by json_extract_path('name', '$... ^ DETAIL: Token "name" is invalid. CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1: name
```

?

**UPDATED_INFO # 3 :**
I use postgresql-14.
I check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html

Looks like it has json_extract_path function (but I got error with it I mentioned above)

I found text :

```
jsonb -> text → jsonb
Extracts JSON object field with the given key.
'{"a": {"b":"foo"}}'::json -> 'a' → {"b":"foo"}
```

it looks like code with

```
'name->"$.en"'
```

But I have an error with it...

**UPDATED_INFO # 4 :**

With

```
$quizCategories = QuizCategory::query()
    ->getByActive()
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("name->>en"), 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I got error :

```
Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "en" does not exist LINE 1: select * from "quiz_categories" order by name->>en desc ^
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to order by? If it's a JSON field, sorting by its value makes no sense. Maybe you want to sort by a "name" subfield or something?

Comment: a)  How in eloquent remake to have sql generated  "quiz_categories"."active" = true(NOT 1)    b) If postgres alows someway of "name" subfield - how can I do it ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I have php 8.1. Does it depends on php version ?

Comment: There was a bug related to your first question on PHP 8.0.4, but your version would be fine. Could you please tag the question "php"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's no order by direct on json field because it's not a primitive type what you can in this case, you have to order by using raw sql.

I'm using order by english use whatever you want from that json column

```php
QuizCategory::query()
    ->getByActive()
    ->orderByRaw('name->"$.en"', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

**TIP**:
No need to specify table in scope function, a short version

```php
public function scopeGetByActive($query, $active = null)
{
  $query->when($active !== null, fn($q) => $q->where('active',$active);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```php
QuizCategory::query()
    ->getByActive()
    orderBy(DB::raw("JSON_EXTRACT('name', '$.en')"), 'desc')
    ->get();
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Please accept my apologies, I was giving you mySQL functions instead of PostgreSQL!

`->` as JSON (if you have nested object you can use for ex: `name->options->>'local'`)

`->>` to get the value as text

```php
QuizCategory::query()
    ->getByActive()
    orderBy(DB::raw("name->>'en'"), 'desc')
    ->get();
```

More details on [JSON in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html)

Comment: Please read UPDATED_INFO :

Comment: Please read UPDATED_INFO # 2:

Comment: My apologies, here is the Postgres Version

Comment: lease read UPDATED_INFO # 3

Comment: don't use `extract_...path` function , use only `"name->>en"` as I mentioned in the 2nd Update

Comment: Please read UPDATED_INFO # 4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255801/discussion-between-othmane-nemli-and-mstdmstd).